# Rotate quad in OpenGL ES 2

Tags: c++, opengl-es-2.0, marmalade

I'm trying to make a simple 2d game in OpenGL ES 2 using marmalde (mostly for learning) and I'm having some problem with rotated quads. The edges of the quads do not look good and I'm guessing that there is something that I'm missing in my code.

I'm rotating the quads by changing the quads corner-positions. I'm drawing the quads like this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `app.icf` file in `data` folder

Add following lines to enable antialising

```
[GL]
EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS=1
EGL_SAMPLES=4
```

Even when you enable `Antialising` it may not work in simulator but will work on devices. Simulator image quality depends on OpenGL ES driver that you select in Configuration -> GL